# Dilation mod p, small gaps

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

If I have a set $A \subset \{1,2,3,...,\epsilon p \} \subset \mathbf{Z}/p \mathbf{Z}$ does there exist a dilation $ \lambda $ such that $ \lambda A$ has no gap larger than $s$ (where $\epsilon = s^{-1}$)? Obviously if A was the whole set then I could just take $s$ for the dilation factor, but what if A isn't the whole thing?

Comment: What is $\epsilon p$? Might help to restate as e.g. $A$ subset of ${1,2,..,k}$ (for some fixed $k \le p$) and restate the gap question in terms of $k$.